# Dynamically change cell values based on cells adjacent

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to do this with a formula but unfortunately it depends on a loop where the cell value is changed dymanically

I'm trying to do this quickly while learning Excel VB but offsets and cell designations are defeating me - anyone care to give me some code :-)

Loop through cells in D to the end of D

```
if Dn = "999" then
if C(n-1) = Cn then
Modify Dn = D(n-1) + 1 else
Modify Dn = 1
```

end

example cells

```
   C     D
1852304 4
1852304 5
1852319 1
1852319 999
1852321 1
1852326 1
1852351 1
1852351 999
1852351 999
1852351 999
1852352 1
1852353 1
1852355 1
1852355 2
1852355 3
```

Comment: you need to post a bit more of your current code as we do not know what DN,C,Cn are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I translate your logic above:

```
Sub sample()
'~~> Declare Variables recommended
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
'~~> this gets hold of the Range Object you want to work in
Set rng = Range("D1", Range("D" & _
    Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
'~~> loop through each cell in range
For Each cel In rng
    '~~> check the value of current cell in range
    If cel.Value = 999 Then
        '~~> use .Offset to check the
        '~~> adjacent cell in C column and compare
        If cel.Offset(-1, -1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
            '~~> Modify Dn
            cel.Value = cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
        Else
            cel.Value = 1
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Result:** Suppose you have this data as in your example.

[image: sample]

After running the macro will become:

[image: result]

Is this what you're trying?